# Enable and Disable Button using Timer in Android

Tags: java, android

I have two Buttons in main View, Button1 and Button2. How can I disable Button1 for specific time period after that time period it should Enable again.

Comment: Use Handler with delay

Comment: It is better to use CountDown Timer from Timer class rather than Handler, because the scope of this would be within the activity.

Comment: Does these solutions work even after the app is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a countdown Timer.

Say you have button button1 ;

```
button1.setEnabled(false);
new CountDownTimer(5000, 10) { //Set Timer for 5 seconds
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
               button1.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }.start()
```

---

Aba: Applied correct View.setEnabled method.

Comment: where should I put Toast in it?

Comment: Put it inside onFinish

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
@Override
  public void run(){
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
}, 5000);
```

Rest, figure out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method. Try this once

```
private void blink(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int timeToBlink = 5000;
            try{
                Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);
            }catch (Exception e) {

            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(button.isEnabled()){
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                    }else{
                        button.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    blink();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

By calling this method You will get the effect you wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun initButton() {
    button.setOnClickListener {

        it.isEnabled = false
        it.postDelayed({ it.isEnabled = true }, 3000)

        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This works in Kt, does require a handler tho

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest way

```
   yourView.setEnabled(false);
   yourView.postDelayed(() -> yourView.setEnabled(true), 5000); // Wait for 5 seconds
```