# Set button visibility gone and visible on selected time for alarm?

Tags: java, android, button, alarmmanager

i am working on project in that i am use alarm manager , i am setting alarm which will ring on 3.40 pm time will show on button , on 3.40 set alarm button need to gone and cancel  button need to visible.

I tried many options those are not working.
help me .

[image: this is the screen shot before alarm set][image: this is after alarm set]

on 3.40 PM that button need to gone and cancel button need to visible

Comment: Have you tried this using service?

Comment: Just for local use (not persistence) https://stackoverflow.com/q/41368127/6576302